# Percona XtraDB Cluster and MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, xtradb-cluster

I've setup a 3-node multi master replication with percona xtradb cluster, it works perfectly.

Now I've tried to add some read-only slaves setting up replication as usual but it seems the binlog doesn't include the new inserts,

I've set binlog_do_db on the master of a database, slave says the log position is the same as the master ones but the new data isn't there.

Is there a special way to do replication on xtradb cluster?

Comment: 1) What is the version of Percona Server in PXC? 2) Are you using MySQL or Percona Server in the ReadOnly Slave? 3) What is `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';` from PXC and the Slaves?

Comment: 1) 5.5.30
2) Plain MySQL from Ubuntu packages
3) PXC = ROW, slave = STATEMENT

now I remember for PXC you have to change the binlog_format. Going to try to change that :)

Comment: On a side note, please make sure all Slaves are running 5.5.x.

Comment: What version of MySQL on the Slaves ? Please run `mysqld --version`

Comment: Version is mysqld Ver 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it seems the binlog doesn't include the new inserts

I'm not sure whether you're saying the binlog actually doesn't include them, and you have confirmed this with [`mysqlbinlog`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html), or that it "seems" like it doesn't, because they don't replicate.

PXC **needs** `log_slave_updates` turned on at the node serving as master to the asynchronous slave, otherwise, not everything will be written to the master's binary log.  This is very different than an ordinary MySQL server as master, where `log_slave_updates` will do nothing at all (unless the master is actually a slave to another master).

If that's not it, remove `replicate_do_db` and `binlog_do_db` and all of their related options from your configuration and then remove them from your brain.  They should never be added unless you know exactly how they work, in your sleep.  The simplest and by far most reliable replication configuration is, and will always be, replicate everything, which is the default.

Forget about `binlog_format` on the slave.  It makes *absolutely* no difference unless the slave, itself, has other, subtended slaves... and if the master is using `ROW` format, the slave will *still* log in `ROW` format if you do indeed have it configured with subtended slaves.  Also, the slave's binlogs (not to be confused with the relay logs) will not log statements received from an upstream master unless `log_slave_updates` is enabled on the slave.

The same thing goes for `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`.  It does not impact actual replication.  It's a setting the determines a tradeoff between ACID compliance and performance.

Comment: Added log_slave_updates and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Binary Log Format** : I was thinking that since Percona XtraDB Cluster (PXC) required using [**binlog_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) as `ROW`, all the read-only Slaves should also have that setting.

**binlog_do_db** : It will record every option for a given database only. Notwithstanding, this is an option that is sometimes misunderstood. [**Please read this blog entry from mysqlperformanceblog**](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/) on how replication can get confused.

Concerning [**binlog_do_db**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db) for ROW based binlogs

> Row-based logging.  Logging is restricted to database db_name. Only
>   changes to tables belonging to db_name are logged; the default
>   database has no effect on this. Suppose that the server is started
>   with --binlog-do-db=sales and row-based logging is in effect, and then
>   the following statements are executed:
>
> ```
> USE prices;
> UPDATE sales.february SET amount=amount+100;
> ```
>
> The changes
>   to the february table in the sales database are logged in accordance
>   with the UPDATE statement; this occurs whether or not the USE
>   statement was issued. However, when using the row-based logging format
>   and --binlog-do-db=sales, changes made by the following UPDATE are not
>   logged:
>
> ```
> USE prices;
> UPDATE prices.march SET amount=amount-25;
> ```
>
> Even if the USE
>   prices statement were changed to USE sales, the UPDATE statement's
>   effects would still not be written to the binary log.
>
> Another important difference in --binlog-do-db handling for
>   statement-based logging as opposed to the row-based logging occurs
>   with regard to statements that refer to multiple databases. Suppose
>   that the server is started with --binlog-do-db=db1, and the following
>   statements are executed:
>
> ```
> USE db1;
> UPDATE db1.table1 SET col1 = 10, db2.table2 SET col2 = 20;
> ```
>
> If you are using statement-based logging, the updates to both tables are
>   written to the binary log. However, when using the row-based format,
>   only the changes to table1 are logged; table2 is in a different
>   database, so it is not changed by the UPDATE. Now suppose that,
>   instead of the USE db1 statement, a USE db4 statement had been used:
>
> ```
> USE db4;
> UPDATE db1.table1 SET col1 = 10, db2.table2 SET col2 = 20;
> ```
>
> In this case, the UPDATE statement is not written to the binary log when
>   using statement-based logging. However, when using row-based logging,
>   the change to table1 is logged, but not that to table2—in other words,
>   only changes to tables in the database named by --binlog-do-db are
>   logged, and the choice of default database has no effect on this
>   behavior.

Based on this, I would suggest, not do binlog_do_db in PXC, but, do [**replicate_do_db**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db) on the Slaves instead.